# Rails 4 + Mongoid + API Calls - Unable to define few conditions

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

In my Rails Application, I am trying to built API for one Model but I am not able to execute few methods. Did nt know where is wrong. Please suggest something.

**Model - User**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  field :display_name, type: String
  field :user_type, type: String
  field :city_id, type: String
  field :country_id, type: String
  field :tags, type: String    
  field :status, type: Mongoid::Boolean
  field :rating, type: Array
end
```

---

API 1. **List of All User - User.All**

But I am not able to take select columns name. Tried in model to define scope but still gives error. ie.

> User.selected_column

```
scope :selected_column, -> { select("id, name") }
```

---

API 2. **List of Top Rated User - User.rating_five**

Tried in model to define scope but still gives error. ie.

> User.rating_five

```
scope :rating_five, -> { .where(:rating["average"] > 4.6 ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mondoid DSL is a bit different from that of Activerecord in some cases. Refer official [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-queries/) here.

First issue:

`scope :selected_column, -> { only(:id, :name) }`

Inorder to select specific columns.

For the second issue, try

`scope :rating_five, -> { gt('rating.average': 4.6) }`

Here `gt` represents `greater than`

Comment: Let me check and let you know If I found any issue. Thanks